# raise exception as http response

Tags: python, django, vue.js, design-patterns

I'm using django and vue to write a Programmer.   Could I raise an exception as a http response, so I can raise the exception anywhere, and do not need to catch it in the django view function, and then reassemble it into a new http response.

Pseudocode

```
try:
  a = ['0']
  b = a[2]
except IndexError as e:
  raise ExceptionAsHttpResponse(status=404, reason='haha')  # Not implemented， hope to get your help.
```

after the **raise ExceptionAsHttpResponse**, the frontend can just accquire the status and reason

Comment: To write a _Programmer_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, you can simply use [`Http404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception). For example:

```
from django.http import Http404

try:
  a = ['0']
  b = a[2]
except IndexError as e:
  raise Http404('your reason')
```

But that is in general should not be practiced, because http response should be generated from view. If you have helper functions or service methods, then it is better to raise a generic error(ie IndexError) from there and catch them in view, then render a error response.